# No update $scope in view after function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-binding

I have an array in my controller called `this.selectedCourses`. This array have some items which are showed in my view as a list. 
After some steps I have this:

```
this.checkAddedCourses = function(studentCourses){
        ...

        if(repeatedCourses.length != 0){
            sweetAlert({
                  title: title,
                  text: text + ' ' + courseList,
                  type: "warning",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                  confirmButtonText: confirmButtonText,
                  closeOnConfirm: false,
                  html: true
                }, 
                function(){
                    angular.forEach(repeatedCourses, function(repeatedCourse){
                        this.removeCoursePurchase(repeatedCourse);
                    }.bind(this));
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your purchase has been refreshed.", "success");
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
```

When the user click on button 'Remove' the items are removed fine from the array, I've already checked, but in my view I still seeing those items until I do something with that array. Is like it isn't refreshing the array after remove the elements.

Thanks.

PD: sweetAlert is a library for alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Use $scope instead of this for data-binding on your view - so $scope.selectedCourses. Remember to pass $scope into your controller as a dependency.

Comment: But why is not woking now? I mean, all my app has been working fine using `this` for data-binding. @oliveromahony

Comment: Maybe because the data gets populated, then the view renders. Then when the data gets changed you need to notify the view somehow, which the this variable isn't doing. Can you post the entire code and a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: it can be done that way also - I prefer the $scope approach, sorry should have included that in my original answer

Comment: Yes, I've put the answer below. Thanks for your help @oliveromahony

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved with the ´$apply´ function using it like this:

```
sweetAlert({
                  title: title,
                  text: text + ' ' + courseList,
                  type: "warning",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                  confirmButtonText: confirmButtonText,
                  closeOnConfirm: false,
                  html: true
                }, 
                function(){
                    angular.forEach(repeatedCourses, function(repeatedCourse){
                        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                            this.removeCoursePurchase(repeatedCourse);
                        }.bind(this));
                    }.bind(this));
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your purchase has been refreshed.", "success");
            }.bind(this));
```